# WPF SSRS report printing

Tags: wpf, reporting, reporting-services

We have an application built in WPF. For reports we are using the Winforms host to display and preview the report. There is a requirement to batch print the SSRS reports physically to a printer. i.e. On click of a button, it should print all the reports on a printer (default printer associated with the machine). The problem we face is that a print dialog appears when we try to print the report. We do not want the print dialog, just direct printing of SSRS report to the pinter. 
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Are the reports hosted on an SSRS instance or are they running locally?

Comment: They are hosted on SSRS instance

Comment: You can download the reports from the report server in a printable format (PDF perhaps?) and then programmatically invoke the print

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate (hence a comment rather than an answer) - batch printing these days is almost *always* indicative of a legacy process. People rarely read these reports so they're a waste of toner and paper. IMHO development resources would be better spent offering the slickest possible experience to enable those users who really do need these reports to get at them in the quickest way possible in soft-copy instead.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? We need a way to do this too. And yes it is a legacy process but in order to move it forward we need to make baby steps in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry about my english.
Steps:
1. you can generate the SSRS report using C# (for example)
2. Instead of displaying a report on the screen, you can export it to PDF (in a temporary folder.)
3. Print this PDF File using a PrintDialog control (Allow you to disable the print dialog).

Probably you can disable the print dialog on the report viewer too but i don't know how.
hope it